# how to add a link to an image contained in a css box model

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, display

I want to put two images one on top of the other on two different lines.
After that the upper image has to be linked to a web page.
However when I write the code, the whole block that contains the upper image
acts like a link, while for my purposes it has just to be the image itself.
I tried again and again but I couldn't do it.
Is there anyone who can give me the solution? Thank you very much for your help!

I tried that way:

html

```
<a href="mappa_full_screen.html"><img class="center" src="img/minimappa.jpg"></a>
<img class="center" src="img/frecciarossa.gif" width="50">
```

css

```
.center { 
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this...

here is a working repl...

https://replit.com/@BenjaminKile/ChocolateFixedProlog#index.html

```html
<img class="center" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" onclick="openUrl('https://picsum.photos/')">
<img class="center" src="https://picsum.photos/200/350" width="50">

<script>
    openUrl = (url) => {
        window.open(url);
    }
</script>

<style>
    .center {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
</style>
```